# Hi-Res images iOS icons

Tags: image, retina-display

I have been given a few images from a powerpoint to use in an iOS app I'm developing, not a graphics guy. How can I make these hi-res, or is there someone can do it for a fee

Comment: If you want help manipulating the images with code, you need to describe the format of the images in detail. If you want to hire someone, maybe try fiverr.  Freelance job listings are off-topic for stackoverflow questions.

Comment: ok, I didn't know that, thanks, I'll delete the post